# Google Apps Script - check if table exist, delete it if it does exist, check if the delete job finished

Tags: google-apps-script, google-bigquery

I am trying to find full reference material of *Google Apps Script -> Advanced Services -> BigQuery*. The [Apps Script BigQuery reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/bigquery) only gives some samples, not covering all the methods.
We are supposed to check the API references for the methods' parameters.

#### Here is what I want to do

1. Check if table exist
2. Delete it if it does exist
3. Check if the delete job has finished

#### Check if Table Exist

#### Delete it if it does exist

I could not find the method to check if a table exists. So I have to just go ahead to delete the table (does not matter if it exists or not), wrap the delete in a try block.

```
try {
  var deleteResults = BigQuery.Tables.remove(project, dataset, table);
  Logger.log(deleteResults);   
} catch (err){
  //return false;
}
```

---

Is this the right way to do the task "check if table exists, if it does, delete it"?

#### Check if delete has finished

Now, I want to know if the job started by

```
BigQuery.Tables.remove(project, dataset, table);
```

has finished, but `Logger.log(deleteResults);` only logged `null`:

```
[18-07-19 14:12:24:927 PDT] null
```

So the `BigQuery.Tables.remove` method does not return anything? How can I know if the delete job is finished?

Comment: Why not use a `DROP TABLE IF EXISTS` statement?

Comment: but question most likely will stay the same  - 'How could I know if the delete job is finished?' :o)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "advanced services", as explained in the docs, are just wrappers to the associated Google APIs. Thus you will not find documentation on the advanced services in Apps Script, as the methods are extensively detailed on the respective API page. You can determine the method signature using either the in-editor autocomplete, or follow [Google's tips](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#how_method_signatures_are_determined)

You can determine if a table exists by either [`list`ing all tables in your project & dataset](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/tables#listing_tables_in_a_dataset), then check for the relevant property (`id`, `friendlyName`, `tableReference.tableId`, etc.), or simply attempt to [`get`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/tables/get) it and handle the associated error (if it didn't exist). If your only goal is to delete it if it exists, your try/catch approach is simplest. Per the API doc for [`table#delete`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/tables/delete), you get an empty response if it was successful.

---

An example Apps Script use of [`BigQuery.Tables.list`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/tables/list) method, which uses [partial responses](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/api-performance) a.k.a. the `"fields"` optional parameter:

```
function getAllTables(projectId, datasetId) {
  const options = {
    fields: "nextPageToken,tables(id,friendlyName,tableReference/tableId)"
  }

  // Collect all tables - there may be more than one page's worth!
  const tables = [];
  do {
    var search = BigQuery.Tables.list(projectId, datasetId, options);
    options.pageToken = search.nextPageToken;
    if (search.tables && search.tables.length)
      Array.prototype.push.apply(tables, search.tables);
  } while (options.pageToken);

  return tables;
}
```

Example rename via [`patch`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/tables/patch):

```
function renameTable(newName, projectId, datasetId, tableId) {
  // The fields and associated new values we're setting.
  const resource = {"friendlyName": newName};
  var response = BigQuery.Tables.patch(resource, projectId, datasetId, tableId);
  // Log the updated table metadata in Stackdriver.
  console.log(response);
}
```

(If you used `update`, you would need to supply the full desired table, rather than just what you're changing.)